# creating a list of matrices in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

Using a for loop, I have generated a list of matrices that are labeled X_1, X_2, X_3, ... etc.

I am now trying to run a series of functions on each matrix and I wrote another for loop:

```
for (i in matrices) {
            df <- count(i)
            df$count <- df$freq
            df$freq <- df$count/nrow(i)  #freq = pi in H1 equation
            for (j in names){
            assign(paste("hap",j,sep="."), df)      
            }
        }
```

I tried to generate the list of matrices using a sequence script:

```
matrices <- (paste("X",seq(1,nrow(windows)), sep="_"))
```

which results in the output: "X_1"  "X_2"  "X_3"  "X_4"  "X_5"
Although this is a list, it is just a list of characters and does not actually reference the matrices.  It seems to work if I manually type in the list of matrix names:

```
matrices <- list(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, ...)
```

but I was hoping to automate this so I can apply the script to large datasets.
If I try combining these with

```
matrices <- list(paste("X",seq(1,nrow(windows)), sep="_"))
```

I get the same thing as the first script: "X_1"  "X_2"  "X_3"  "X_4"  "X_5"

Is there a way to generate sequential lists of matrices so they can be used in a for loop?

I have also tried lapply, but I am less comfortable with this than loops and I could not get the functions I wanted to do to work in lapply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about this by adding each matrix to a list at the time you actually create each matrix, e.g.

```
lst <- list(X_1, X_2, ..., X_N)
```

Then, when you want to apply a function to each matrix you can simply use `lapply`, e.g.

```
result <- lapply(lst, function(x) fun(x))
```

where `fun()` takes a matrix as input and does something with it.

Comment: You can use `mget` i.e. `lst <- mget(paste0("X_", 1:N))` where `N <- 5`